# Shell script for creating a numbered list of files

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm a shell script beginner. I've been trying to figure this out for some time already and I still have no idea, how I should write this shell script so that it works. I have multiple text files with data in them. What I need is to write a script that would create a numbered list of containing the data from the files.

Example: I have four files, "file_A", "file_B", "file_C" and "file_D". There's some text in each of them. Basically I need to transfer it into a new file using something like "script.sh output_file file_A file_B file_C file_D", so that the output file looks like this:

1. file_A "Text from file_A"
2. file_B "Text from file_B"
3. file_C "Text from file_C"
4. file_D "Text from file_D"

Okay, now I know I can redirect echo "$file_#" and cat "$file_#" to the >>"$output_file", but how do I make it work repeatedly for a larger amount of input files using the arguments? I guess I'll need to use for loop, right? How do I add the numbering? Shall I set a variable for this row counting function?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Nothing, that worked. To be honest, I have absolutely no idea. I mean, I don't even know how I should use "for FILE; do...", so that it does not include the first arg. I know what commands are probably needed to be used to construct the script, but I don't know how to use the together. I can see the usage of for, do, done; cat; echo; >>; maybe shift and then some arithmetic expansion for numbering, but that's about it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways to do it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# first argument is output file
output_file=$1 
shift

# shift through rest of the arguments
while [ $# -ne 0 ] 
do
    echo "$((counter+=1)). $1 '$(cat $1)'" >> $output_file
    shift
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked well. Thank you for the script and for the explanation. I'm glad I got two different answers, that helped me understand the problem much better. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below solution, it worked for me

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #index to refer file number
    index=0
    #var to store output file name
    outputFile="$1"
    #clear output file before writing
    echo "" > $outputFile
    #iterate through all args
    for file in "$@"
    do
            if [ $index -eq 0 ] #skip first arg as it contain output file  
            then
                    index=$((index+1))
                    continue
            fi
            echo "$index. $file " `cat $file` >> $outputFile  #append file index, name & text to output file
            index=$((index+1))
    done
```

**Output:**

1. file1  Random txt 1
2. file2  Random txt 2

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked well. Thank you for the script and for the explanation. I'm glad I got two different answers, that helped me understand the problem much better. :)